# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Audio failure

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2.  This is a new installation, but I was able to play audio through speakers or headphones yesterday by selecting the desired output in the Sound|Output dialog.  Today, I only get headphones.

The curious thing is that, in the Sound|Output dialog, there is an Output volume slider bar.  When I click on the slider tab, there is a "popping" sound that plays through my speakers!  This is not an audio artifact, I believe it to be an audio waveform that plays a pop.  I can select my headphones, click on the slider tab, and hear this same waveform through my headphones.

I have looked all over the web and tried a number of the suggested solutions, but so for none of them have worked.

The Sound|Output dialog lists 7 possible outputs:

1. HDMI/DisplayPort Barts HDMI Audio [Radion HD6800 Series]
2. Digital Output (S/PDIF) Built-in Audio
3. Analog Output Built-in Audio
4. Digital Output (S/PDIF) SoundBlaster Live! 24-bit External SB0490
5. Analog Output SoundBlaster Live! 24-bit External SB0490
6. Digital Output (S/PDIF) Wireless Audio
7. Analog Output Wireless Audio

4 through 7 worked yesterday.  Today, only 6 and 7 can play the Sound|Output dialog's Test Sound, but I can still get a clear popping sound on all of 4 through 7.